# Importation multiple dcm images

Tags: image-processing

I'm extremely new to Mathematica. I want to import 201 .dcm (DICOM) files into Mathematica 9. Is there a way to do this which doesn't require my doing it an image at a time?

My ultimate need to is to then create a 3D image from these files.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Quite simple:

```
files = FileNames["somePath/*.dicom"];
imgs = Map[Import, files];
```

Where `Filenames` finds all files in some path and `Map` applies the function `Import` to every list item in the second parameter.

If you want a progress indicator (probably a good idea for 200 images), you can do this:

```
files = FileNames["somePath/*.dicom"];
imgs = Monitor[Table[Import[files[[i]]], {i, Length[files]}], 
         ProgressIndicator[i/Length[files]]];
```